# mariadb - fresh install fails on reboot

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, apache-2.4, mariadb

Been trawling around for a solution to this for a while. Initially in attempting to run mysql i am getting :

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

There's quite a bit of info on this but none really got me anywhere.

Digging around a bit more it would seem that the fault is that the startup fails on a timeout when it is trying to load.

On uninstalling mariadb and following the install process afresh the system works as expected... Until a reboot of the server then nothing! The socket error as above. I am along the line of thought that the socket error is secondary to the service not even running after the reboot.

Prior to rebooting service commands for start, stop, restart and reload work fine.

I am running UFW without any ports enabled for MySQL, but I am not yet tapping into the server remotely so assuming that this isn't a problem - all access to the db is/(will be) from the local file system via hosted pages.

I am running latest stable Ubuntu, encrypted home directory and which was installed with the LAMP option. I uninstalled what I thought was MySQL (but might have been MariaDB already) in favour of installing MariaDB. Now these problems. Prior to the initial uninstall the server was a fresh ubuntu install (and no hdd capacity problems) and i hadnt tested mysql before that so cant comment on the error before this.

I am rather stuck as to where to investigate next so your thoughts would be appreciated.

Also of note I dont seem to have a mariadb*.log or mysql*.log file to interrogate as per some suggestions

`service mariadb status` as follows:

```
● mariadb.service - MariaDB 10.2.14 database server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mariadb.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/mariadb.service.d
           └─migrated-from-my.cnf-settings.conf
   Active: failed (Result: timeout) since Sat 2018-04-14 13:01:43 BST; 1min 28s ago
     Docs: man:mysqld(8)
           https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/systemd/
  Process: 1362 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld $MYSQLD_OPTS $_WSREP_NEW_CLUSTER $_WSREP_START_POSITION (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 1074 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c [ ! -e /usr/bin/galera_recovery ] && VAR= ||   VAR=`/usr/bin/galera_recovery`; [ $? -eq 0 ]   && systemctl set-environment _WSREP_START_POSITION=$VAR || exit
  Process: 1061 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c systemctl unset-environment _WSREP_START_POSITION (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 1014 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/install -m 755 -o mysql -g root -d /var/run/mysqld (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 1362 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
      CPU: 574ms

Apr 14 13:01:40 smcserver systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Start operation timed out. Terminating.
Apr 14 13:01:41 smcserver mysqld[1362]: 2018-04-14 13:01:41 139873867650816 [Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
Apr 14 13:01:41 smcserver mysqld[1362]: 2018-04-14 13:01:41 139873151330048 [Note] InnoDB: Dumping buffer pool(s) to /var/lib/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
Apr 14 13:01:41 smcserver mysqld[1362]: 2018-04-14 13:01:41 139873151330048 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) dump completed at 180414 13:01:41
Apr 14 13:01:43 smcserver mysqld[1362]: 2018-04-14 13:01:43 139873867650816 [Note] InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 1620137
Apr 14 13:01:43 smcserver mysqld[1362]: 2018-04-14 13:01:43 139873867650816 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "ibtmp1"
Apr 14 13:01:43 smcserver mysqld[1362]: 2018-04-14 13:01:43 139873867650816 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete
Apr 14 13:01:43 smcserver systemd[1]: Failed to start MariaDB 10.2.14 database server.
Apr 14 13:01:43 smcserver systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Unit entered failed state.
Apr 14 13:01:43 smcserver systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Failed with result 'timeout'.
```

And this is my `journalctl -u mariadb.service` log:

```
Apr 14 13:00:06 smcserver systemd[1]: Starting MariaDB 10.2.14 database server...
Apr 14 13:00:14 smcserver mysqld[1362]: 2018-04-14 13:00:14 139874051098816 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 10.2.14-MariaDB-10.2.14+maria~artful-log) starting as process 1362 ...
Apr 14 13:00:16 smcserver mysqld[1362]: 2018-04-14 13:00:16 139874051098816 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
Apr 14 13:00:16 smcserver mysqld[1362]: 2018-04-14 13:00:16 139874051098816 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
Apr 14 13:00:16 smcserver mysqld[1362]: 2018-04-14 13:00:16 139874051098816 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
Apr 14 13:00:16 smcserver mysqld[1362]: 2018-04-14 13:00:16 139874051098816 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
Apr 14 13:00:16 smcserver mysqld[1362]: 2018-04-14 13:00:16 139874051098816 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
Apr 14 13:00:16 smcserver mysqld[1362]: 2018-04-14 13:00:16 139874051098816 [Note] InnoDB: Using generic crc32 instructions
Apr 14 13:00:16 smcserver mysqld[1362]: 2018-04-14 13:00:16 139874051098816 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 256M, instances = 1, chunk size = 128M
Apr 14 13:00:16 smcserver mysqld[1362]: 2018-04-14 13:00:16 139874051098816 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
Apr 14 13:00:16 smcserver mysqld[1362]: 2018-04-14 13:00:16 139873311708928 [Note] InnoDB: If the mysqld execution user is authorized, page cleaner thread priority can be changed. See the man page
Apr 14 13:00:17 smcserver mysqld[1362]: 2018-04-14 13:00:17 139874051098816 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
Apr 14 13:00:17 smcserver mysqld[1362]: 2018-04-14 13:00:17 139874051098816 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
Apr 14 13:00:17 smcserver mysqld[1362]: 2018-04-14 13:00:17 139874051098816 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
Apr 14 13:00:17 smcserver mysqld[1362]: 2018-04-14 13:00:17 139874051098816 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file './ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
Apr 14 13:00:17 smcserver mysqld[1362]: 2018-04-14 13:00:17 139874051098816 [Note] InnoDB: File './ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
Apr 14 13:00:18 smcserver mysqld[1362]: 2018-04-14 13:00:18 139874051098816 [Note] InnoDB: 5.7.21 started; log sequence number 1620109
Apr 14 13:00:18 smcserver mysqld[1362]: 2018-04-14 13:00:18 139873151330048 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from /var/lib/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
Apr 14 13:00:18 smcserver mysqld[1362]: 2018-04-14 13:00:18 139873151330048 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 180414 13:00:18
Apr 14 13:00:18 smcserver mysqld[1362]: 2018-04-14 13:00:18 139874051098816 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
Apr 14 13:00:18 smcserver mysqld[1362]: 2018-04-14 13:00:18 139874051098816 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '127.0.0.1'.
Apr 14 13:00:19 smcserver mysqld[1362]: 2018-04-14 13:00:19 139874051098816 [Note] Reading of all Master_info entries succeded
Apr 14 13:00:19 smcserver mysqld[1362]: 2018-04-14 13:00:19 139874051098816 [Note] Added new Master_info '' to hash table
Apr 14 13:00:19 smcserver mysqld[1362]: 2018-04-14 13:00:19 139874051098816 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
Apr 14 13:00:19 smcserver mysqld[1362]: Version: '10.2.14-MariaDB-10.2.14+maria~artful-log'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  mariadb.org binary distribution
Apr 14 13:01:40 smcserver mysqld[1362]: 2018-04-14 13:01:40 139873867650816 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (initiated by: unknown): Normal shutdown
Apr 14 13:01:40 smcserver mysqld[1362]: 2018-04-14 13:01:40 139873193293568 [Note] InnoDB: FTS optimize thread exiting.
Apr 14 13:01:40 smcserver mysqld[1362]: 2018-04-14 13:01:40 139873867650816 [Note] Event Scheduler: Purging the queue. 0 events
Apr 14 13:01:40 smcserver systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Start operation timed out. Terminating.
Apr 14 13:01:41 smcserver mysqld[1362]: 2018-04-14 13:01:41 139873867650816 [Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
Apr 14 13:01:41 smcserver mysqld[1362]: 2018-04-14 13:01:41 139873151330048 [Note] InnoDB: Dumping buffer pool(s) to /var/lib/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
Apr 14 13:01:41 smcserver mysqld[1362]: 2018-04-14 13:01:41 139873151330048 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) dump completed at 180414 13:01:41
Apr 14 13:01:43 smcserver mysqld[1362]: 2018-04-14 13:01:43 139873867650816 [Note] InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 1620137
Apr 14 13:01:43 smcserver mysqld[1362]: 2018-04-14 13:01:43 139873867650816 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "ibtmp1"
Apr 14 13:01:43 smcserver mysqld[1362]: 2018-04-14 13:01:43 139873867650816 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete
Apr 14 13:01:43 smcserver systemd[1]: Failed to start MariaDB 10.2.14 database server.
Apr 14 13:01:43 smcserver systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Unit entered failed state.
Apr 14 13:01:43 smcserver systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Failed with result 'timeout'.
```

Comment: Was this version of mariadb shipped with Ubuntu or did you obtain it elsewhere?

Comment: It was obtained via apt-get after running this from the instructions I followed: ------- `sudo apt-get install software-properties-common`  -------
`sudo apt-key adv --recv-keys --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 0xF1656F24C74CD1D8`
-------- `sudo add-apt-repository 'deb [arch=amd64,i386] http://mirrors.ukfast.co.uk/sites/mariadb/repo/10.2/ubuntu artful main'`

Comment: Are you using monit

Answer (score 1):

How much ram is on the system, as long as you are sudo when try to start mysql you also need atleast 1GB of Ram to start it.